# nginx proxy redirect with fastapi routers

Tags: nginx, fastapi, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am attempting to develop a web app with nginx and fastapi and react. These are all new to me.

Regarding the fastapi, I have a main `FastAPI` that has a login route. I have added additional routes with `APIRouter` class and `FastAPI.include_router` method. I refered to this [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/bigger-applications/)

**Development setup**

- fastapi runs on port 8000 with uvicorn
- react frontend runs on port 5000 with `npm start`
- axios base url is `localhost:8000`

Everything works as expected and the axios calls return correct response.

**Production setup**

- fastapi runs on port 80 with gunicorn
- frontend built with `npm build`
- axios base url is `localhost`
- all request handled with nginx in frontend

I based the following nginx conf file on this [documentation](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/deploy.html)

```
# conf file for server

# proxy pass for api requests
upstream api {
    server backend;
}

# main server for app
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/frontend;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/frontend;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://api;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

Note that I am using docker compose and have a backend service and a frontend service.
With this configuration the login route works correctly, but the routes added via `FastAPI.include_router` return HTTP 307 redirect and the response header shows requested url as `http://api/api/path/to/route` instead of `http://localhost/api/path/to/route`. So it appears that nginx successfully proxy passes requests for a route directly in the main fastapi app module but redirects to the wrong url for requests to routes added with `app.include_router`. According to this [reference](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/deploy.html), I should have `proxy_redirect off;` in the `/api` location block, but if I remove this line, then nginx redirects the request and returns the correct response.

**question**

- why is nginx redirecting the request even when I include `proxy_redirect off;` in the conf file.
- why does the redirect not return the correct response unless I remove `proxy_redirect off;`